# android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE don't recived on unsuccessful download

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have  reciver that registered to android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.listener.DownloadListenerService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And it is my reciver DownloadListenerService.java:

```
package com.myapp.listener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DownloadListenerService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MYAPP","Start DownloadListenerService");
        //some code
    }
}
```

And i see in logcat message "Start DownloadListenerService" only when download is complete. But if download get status in download manager unsuccessful i don't see any messages in logcat. How i can catch that my download is not downloaded?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an `if else` statement

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (context != null){
        Log.d("MYAPP","Start DownloadListenerService");
        //some code
    }else{
        Log.d("MYAPP","Fail DownloadListenerService");
        //some code
    }
 return;
}
```

**EDIT :** I think this will return true even if your download failed, so maybe substitute `(context != null)` with something else? Maybe `(file != null)`

Comment: the problem is that onReceive is not called at all when download is failed

Comment: @Anton111111 can you post your code on how you start the service? Maybe there's something there we can help you with